# Interaction requirements for user-item data for Content Based Filtering RS

Tags: recommender-system

I am trying to build a recommender system using content based filtering for recipes. I am new to recommender systems. My user-item interactions table contains mostly users who have only rated one item - around 35%. Will this be a problem for building/training a CBF system?

Thanks!